# How do I make Figma exported HTML, CSS code responsive

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, responsive

I recently exported a Figma design into Angular code, but I'm struggling with making it responsive due to the large codebase. I've tried using media queries, but the code primarily uses (px) units, and there are hundreds to thousands of CSS classes, which makes it time-consuming.

I also attempted to use Bootstrap, but unfortunately, it didn't yield the desired results. I'm seeking advice on the best approach to this process.

Answer (score 0):

**figma to html and css convert -> try figma locofy plugin**

I have used this, its result is very good but you are not fond of HTML and CSS, so this is a negative point for it. first learn HTML and CSS

**result** -> figma locofy plugin + Html and CSS = responsive design

Comment: No I am very familiar, but if i had started the project from scratch it'd have been easy to make it easy to make it responsive. Unfortunately, The design was already made using Figma, I have the working code but making responsive is challenging for me

Comment: I have used TeleportHQ plugin to export the code into Angular

Comment: I need to know the actual approach that developers would take in this case